# How does gPRC interact with PHP flow of execution?

Tags: php, microservices, grpc

I know that queue of messages (like Kafka, RabbitMQ, etc.) is commonly used for communication purpose between microservices. The common schema of communication between microservices is simple - when event occurs it is published to the queue, then microservices' workers who are subscribed on topic receive a message about an event. This approach allows you to bypass the blocking of the flow of execution, when the event affected several microservices.

So, I learned about gRPC and I have question about it - gRPC uses HTTP/2 protocol: Does gRPC HTTP Request blocking PHP flow of execution?

Comment: Not sure I follow the question.  gRPC is a connection protocol, and PHP is a scripting language.  PHP scripts may or may not block when servicing gRPC calls depending on how they're implemented.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer thanks for comment, "gRPC calls depending on how they're implemented" — that's what I wanted to clarify